# Azure Service Bus Queue Performance

Tags: azure, performance, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using the Azure service bus queue for one of my requirements. The requirement is simple, an azure function will act as an API and creates multiple jobs in the queue. The function is scalable and on-demand new instance creation. The job which microservice creates will be processed by a windows service. So the sender is Azure function and the receiver is windows service. Since the azure function is scalable, there will be multiple numbers of functions will be executed in parallel. So, the number of jobs getting created into the queue will be in parallel, and probably one job in every 500MS. Windows service is a single instance that is a Queue listener listens to this Queue and executes in parallel. So, the number of senders might be more, the receiver is one instance. And each job can run in parallel must be limited(4, since it takes more time and CPU) Right now, I am using Aure Service Bus Queue with the following configuration. My doubt is which configuration produces the best performance for this particular requirement.

The deletion of the Job in the queue will not be an issue for me. So, Can I use Delete instead of Peek-Lock?

Also, right now, the number of items receiving by the listener is not in order. I want to maintain an order in which it got created. My requirement is maximum performance. The job is done by the windows service is a CPU intensive task, that's why I have limited to 4 since the system is a 4 Core.

Max delivery count: 4, Message lock duration: 5 min, MaxConcurrentCalls: 4 (In listener). I am new to the service bus, I need a suggestion for this.

One more doubt is, let's consider the listener got 4 jobs in parallel and start execution. One job completed its execution and became a completed status. So the listener will pick the next item immediately or wait for all the 4 jobs to be completed (MaxConcurrentCalls: 4).

Answer (score 1):

> The deletion of the Job in the queue will not be an issue for me. So, Can I use Delete instead of Peek-Lock?

Receiving messages in `PeekLock` receive mode will less performant than `ReceiveAndDelete`. You'll be saving roundtrips to the broker to complete messages.

> Max delivery count: 4, Message lock duration: 5 min, MaxConcurrentCalls: 4 (In listener). I am new to the service bus, I need a suggestion for this.

`MaxDeliveryCount` is how many times a message can be attempted before it's dead-lettered. It appears to be equal to the number of cores, but it shouldn't. Could be just a coincidence.

`MessageLockDuration` will only matter if you use `PeekLock` receive mode. For `ReceiveAndDelete` it won't matter.

As for Concurrency, even though your work is CPU bound, I'd benchmark if higher concurrency would be possible.

An additional parameter on the message receiver to look into would be `PrefetchCount`. It can improve the overall performance by making fewer roundtrips to the broker.

> One more doubt is, let's consider the listener got 4 jobs in parallel and start execution. One job completed its execution and became a completed status. So the listener will pick the next item immediately or wait for all the 4 jobs to be completed (MaxConcurrentCalls: 4).

The listener will immediately start processing the 5th message as your concurrency is set to 4 and one message processing has been completed.

> Also, right now, the number of items receiving by the listener is not in order. I want to maintain an order in which it got created.

To process messages in the order they were sent in you will need to send and receive messages using [sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).

> My requirement is maximum performance. The job is done by the windows service is a CPU intensive task, that's why I have limited to 4 since the system is a 4 Core.

There are multiple things to take into consideration. The location of your Windows Service location would impact the latency and message throughput. Scaling out could help, etc.